# is it possible to use pTooptip if text overflow

Tags: angular, primeng

```
is it possible to use pTooptip if text overflow
```

```css
.ellipsis-text{
        @include setWhiteSpace(nowrap);
        @include setTextOverflowToEllipsis();
        display: $block;
        overflow: $hidden;
    }
```

```html
<span class="ellipsis-text" id="attchPTooltip" pTooltip="abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc"> 
abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
</span>
```

I want to use this pToolTip only if there is text overflow other wise no tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend use Length property of string to find the length and if it is more than (30, 40 ... etc) then use Tooltip or else show the text like below. You can use ngSwitch or ngIf.

```
<span *ngIf="data.length > 30">
     <button class="btn btn-default"  pTooltip={{data._id}}></button>
</span>
<span *ngIf="data.length > 30">{{data._id}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this :
http://codebuckets.com/2018/01/23/angular-pipe-to-truncate-text-to-the-nearest-whole-word/

And you can use "tooltipDisabled" attribute if the string length is not too much.